# Call function when script has initialised and when something changes

Tags: javascript, json

I'm using [Vanilla Calendar](https://vanilla-calendar.com/) to show if events exist on certain days within my JSON data. Each day that has an event has a square that represents an event with a different background colour depending on the category it has associated to it. You can see it working [here](https://codepen.io/OnTheWeb/pen/gOZNzYz).

my function which adds the div tags on the days for each event:

```
assignEventsToCalendar = function(){
    let eventData = data.events;

    for (const entry of eventData) {
        for (const [month, days] of Object.entries(entry)) {
            for (const dayObject of days) {
                for (const [day, events] of Object.entries(dayObject)) {
                    let dayElement = document.querySelector(`[data-calendar-day="${day}"]`);
                    let eventWrapper = document.createElement("div");
                    eventWrapper.classList.add("event-wrapper");
                    dayElement.append(eventWrapper);

                    for (const eventObject of events) {
                        for (const [eventId, details] of Object.entries(eventObject)) {
                            for (const event of details) {
                                let singleEvent = document.createElement("div");
                                singleEvent.classList.add("event", event.category);
                                eventWrapper.append(singleEvent);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

My issue is that when I change the month, the events disappear as I'm only calling the function to fetch and add the events to each day on the calendar on page load

I'm looking to have the function run/show the events for that month whenever the month is changed

From the docs, I can see there is a '[get and change every day](https://vanilla-calendar.com/docs/learn/action-handlers/get-and-change-every-day)' handler which I have in my code like this:

```
actions: {
   getDays(day, date, HTMLElement, HTMLButtonElement) {
       HTMLButtonElement.style.flexDirection = 'column';
       HTMLButtonElement.innerHTML = `
          <span>${day}</span>
          <span style="font-size: 8px;color: #8BC34A;">some txt</span>
       `;
   }
}
```

It is adding a span with some test text ('some txt') to each day on the calendar

I'm thinking I can use this handler to apply my div to each day that an event exists in the JSON data. Maybe I need this in combination with my function but I'm unsure

Can anyone assist with how I can get this logic to work?